# Can a Gaussian surface have infinitesimally small thickness?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, gauss-law

This question originated while solving the charge density with the variation of electric field potential known. The potential in space varies as $\phi=-ax^3+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. To find the charge density $\rho(x)$, first $\overline{E}$ can be found using $\mathrm d\phi=-\overline{E}\cdot\mathrm d\overline{r}$ and it comes out to be $\overline{E}=3ax^2 \hat{\mathrm i}$. Now the charge distribution can be very easily computed using differential form of Gauss' law: $\overline{\nabla}\cdot\overline{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0$.

Consider the integral form of Gauss' law, $\oint\overline{E}\cdot\mathrm d\overline{A}=q_{\text{enc}}/\epsilon_0$. Consider the Gaussian surface to be a cuboid of thickness $\mathrm dx$, length $l$ and height $h$. Since $\overline{E}$ is about the same for $x$ and $x+\mathrm dx$, the expression can be rewritten as $(3ax^2)(lh)\epsilon_0=\int_{0}^{x}\rho(x)lh\mathrm dx $. Differentiating both sides seems to give $\rho(x)$ as $12a\epsilon_0x$, while using the differential form gives $\rho(x)=6a\epsilon_0x$.

So can a Gaussian surface be of infinitesimal dimensions?

Comment: Your last sentence asks the opposite of your title.

Answer (score 5):

A Gaussian surface is a mathematical two-dimensional surface with *zero* thickness. You don’t integrate the field inside it. You integrate the flux of the field *across* it.